# How to return all rows even if the query is NULL

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have following code:

```
SELECT t1.location as Locations,  
COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total,
tab.Responses, tab.location as tablocation 
FROM `trespondent` t1  
JOIN 
( SELECT location, COUNT( location ) AS Responses FROM  `trespondent`  
WHERE completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete') GROUP BY location ) 
tab ON t1.location = tab.location GROUP BY t1.location
```

The output of this is:

```
Locations   Total   Responses   tablocation
Berlin      57      43          Berlin
New York    132     118         New York
```

Which is fine.  However, I have another 'location' in the database (Paris) that has a total of 55 but has a result of 0 for responses (i.e. `WHERE completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete'`).

My ideal output would be:

```
Locations   Total   Responses   tablocation
Berlin      57      43          Berlin
New York    132     118         New York
Paris       55      0           Paris
```

However, I am struggling to as I cannot get MySQL to return the row as the statement produces a 'NULL' result.

I've tried using `UNION` but I'm having problems - I think it is because I'm using a sub-query.  Any and all advise welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try do add LEFT OUTER JOIN  in the SELECT in order to get also the values null, in other words if from a select you do not get any value (like Paris) so for that part of SELECT you LEFT OUTER JOIN  instead of other kind of join.

For more details see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

bye

Comment: I've spent a good couple of hours fiddling around with trying to UNION to work and a simple left join would have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` along with [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function like below

```
SELECT t1.location as Locations,  
COUNT( t1.location ) AS Total,
COALESCE(tab.Responses, 0), 
COALESCE(tab.location, t1.location) as tablocation 
FROM `trespondent` t1  
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT location, 
COUNT( location ) AS Responses 
FROM  `trespondent`  
WHERE completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete') 
GROUP BY location 
) tab ON t1.location = tab.location 
GROUP BY t1.location
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to fix your code might be to `LEFT JOIN` to the subquery and use `COALESCE(tab.Responses, 0)` to deal with nulls.

However, it's a poorly-written query and there are other things you should fix. For example, this is essentially a self-join where you're imposing the condition that `t1.location = tab.location` – there's no point in separately returning both columns as they will *always* be identical.

(An interesting implication of the self-join: If `location` is not a unique key in your table, you could have nulls in that column; inner joining with the condition you've used would eliminate those rows from your result set, since the join condition would be `null = null` [which is not considered true](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).)

Also, you're grouping by the same column twice. This is a strong sign that your query might have a simpler formulation. Try this out instead, and compare the results (more importantly, compare the execution plans using `EXPLAIN`):

```
SELECT
  location,
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete')) AS responses
FROM
  trespondent
GROUP BY location;
```

If you need to deal with nulls in the `responses` column, you can wrap it in `COALESCE` as suggested above or alternatively use [the MySQL-specific function `IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).